Did the text or terms of Hunter Biden's pardon differ from those previously issued by US Presidents? How?
Presidential pardons are a provision of the US Constitution:*

The pardon power of the president is based on Article II, Section 2,
Clause 1 of the U.S. Constitution, which provides: The President ...
shall have Power to grant Reprieves and Pardons for Offenses against
the United States, except in Cases of impeachment. The U.S. Supreme
Court has interpreted the provision to include the power to grant
pardons, conditional pardons, commutations of sentence, conditional
commutations of sentence, remissions of fines and forfeitures,
respites and amnesties.Wikipedia

The Supreme Court has handed down some decisions related to the powers of pardon, but the power appears to be fairly broad.
Since both Biden and Trump seem bent on expanding pardon powers to the maximum extent allowed by the Constitution and the Court, it is important to determine exactly what power presidents have in this regard. Texts of pardons and their specific wording are carefully composed to adhere to both the Constitution and the Supreme Court's previous opinions on pardons.

Just going to add a note of context. One of the original arguments for giving the President the power to pardon was as a method to counter political persecution by opposition parties. It was one of the few monarchical power viewed as necessary.

@DavidS Also worth noting that there were no direct appeals of criminal convictions in federal courts until the 1890s and the scope of habeas corpus review of criminal convictions was very narrow (the existence of a conviction by a court with jurisdiction was generally all that was probed). The need for the pardon power to correct errors in the court process was much greater for the first century of the current U.S. Constitution than it is now (and is reflected by much lower rates of pardon grants since direct appeals of federal criminal convictions became available).

How about the pardon being given by a suspect in some of the crimes for which the pardon is given? It is credibly alleged that Hunter Biden was Jospeh Biden's stand-in for reception of money or other duties as part of Biden Sr.'s corrupt dealings (e.g. in Ukraine).

President Ford gave Nixon a full, absolute, and unconditional pardon for all crimes against the United States from January 20, 1969 to August 9, 1974.  This covered the entirety of Nixon's presidency and spanned more than 5.5 years.  Hunter's pardon differs only in that it covers roughly 11 years instead of roughly 5.5, and that he is a relative of the President (as opposed to having hand-picked him as his VP just weeks before).  But the pardoning of relatives is no longer a new thing, as both Bill Clinton and Donald Trump have pardoned their relatives, and evidently long before them Abraham Lincoln pardoned his wife's half-sister.
As such the pardon is definitely not unprecedented.  Though both are a significant departure from the norm, which you can find details about in Jeff Diver's answer.

Which previous presidents have pardoned their family members?

That being said, since Nixon none of them are - relative to that one - in any way questionable. But only because that was insanely bad for the rule of law and justice to an unimagineable degree

@RickSmith So in short, the great Lincoln still holds the record.

Pardons vary greatly based on the circumstances surrounding the offense.
The exact text of Hunter Biden's pardon reads: 

For those offenses against the United States which he has committed or
may have committed or taken part in during the period from January 1,
2014 through December 1, 2024, including but not limited to all
offenses charged or prosecuted (including any that have resulted in
convictions) by Special Counsel David C. Weiss in Docket No.
1:23-cr-00061-MN in the United States District Court for the District
of Delaware and Docket No. 2:23-CR-00599-MCS-1 in the United States
District Court for the Central District of California.

Pardon texts since 1969 (Nixon presidency)are available online from the Office of the Pardon Attorney.Clemency Recipients
Pardons have been customarily issued upon the recommendation of the Department of Justice, like so: Executive Grant of Clemancy




AFTER CONSIDERING the applications for executive clemency of the
following named persons and a letter from the Department ofJustice
recommending executive clemency in each case, I hereby grant full and
unconditional pardons to the following named persons for those
offenses against the United States described in each such
recommendation: JASON HERNANDEZ BEYERL Y HOLCY, AKA BEYERL Y CANTY
JEFFREY ALAN LEWIS BOBBY DARRELL LOWERY JESSE MOSLEY, AKA JESSIE
MOSLEY KATRINA POLK GLENN RAY ROYAL AKA GLENN RAY ROYAL, JR. ALEXIS
SUTTON RICKY DONNELL TYLER AKA RICK TYLER STACYL. WILDER PILAR
ALEJANDRA YELICIE-RODRIGUEZ I HEREBY DESIGNATE, direct, and empower
the Pardon Attorney, as my representative, to sign each grant
of clemency to the persons named herein. The Pardon Attorney shall
declare that her action is the act of the President, being performed at
my direction.

Sometimes they can be very detailed and contain specific provisions that allow them to be revoked under various circumstances, for example:






BE IT KNOWN, THAT THIS DAY, I, JOSEPH R. BIDEN, JR., PRESIDENT OF THE
UNITED STATES, PURSUANT TO MY POWERS UNDER ARTICLE II, SECTION 2,
CLAUSE 1, OF THE CONSTITUTION, AFTER CONSIDERING THE APPLICATION FOR
EXECUTIVE CLEMENCY, HAVE GRANTED UNTO VADIM KONOSHCHENOK A FULL PARDON
FOR THOSE OFFENSES charged in indictments (Docket No. 1
:22-cr-00409-HG-5) filed in the United States District Court for the
Eastern District of New York on December 5, 2022 and May 22, 2023, for
violations of (Count One): Sections 371 and 3551 et seq., Title 18,
United States Code; (Count Fourteen): Sections 4819(a)(l),
4819(a)(2)(A)-(G), and 4819(b), Title 50, United States Code, and
Sections 736.2(b)(I) and 746.8(a)(l), Title 15, Code of Federal
Regulations; and (Count Fifteen): Sections 554(a), 2, and 3551 et
seq., Title 18, United States Code. I CONDITION THE PARDON UPON THE
FOLLOWING TERMS: (1) the said VADIM KONOSHCHENOK shall depart the
United States; (2) the said VADIM KONOSHCHENOK shall thereafter remain
outside the limits of the United States, its territories, and its
possessions; (3) the said VADIM KONOSHCHENOK shall not commit any
additional crime against the United States or in violation of the laws
of the United States subsequent to the acceptance of this Pardon; (4)
the said VADIM KoNOSHCHENOK shall waive and release any and all
claims, demands, rights, and causes of action of whatsoever kind and
nature against the United States of America, its agents, servants, and
employees; (5) the said V ADIM KONOSHCHENOK shall waive any and all
claims to funds or property already seized or subject to forfeiture as
part of the prosecution of offenses subject to this Pardon; and (6) the
said VADIM KONOSHCHENOK shall not accept or otherwise receive any
financial benefit directly or indirectly, in any manner or amount,
from any book, movie, or other publication or production, in any form
or media, about the circumstances surrounding the instant charges or
Pardon. IF AT ANY TIME the said VADIM KONOSHCHENOK violates any one or
more of the aforementioned conditions, as determined by me in my
complete discretion ( or by a future President in his or her complete
discretion), this Pardon may be voided in its entirety.

As you can see from the examples above, Hunter Biden's pardon differs from these for its blanket coverage of incidents during the decade from January 1,
2014 through December 1, 2024, as well as specific convictions for violation of law.

It's strange you bring up Nixon but not Ford's pardon of Nixon, which was similarly a blanket pardon of everything and covered many months.  Hunter's pardon differs substantially from Nixon's only in the amount of time covered. And both Bill Clinton and Trump pardoned relatives, if you want to somehow go that route.

Actually, make that many years: Jan 20 1969 to Aug 9 1974. More than 5.5 years, his entire presidency.
